# Ability to specify mmenu container on page to slide menu over

Tags: mmenu

We're looking at whether we can specify the container in which the menu will slide in over as currently it slides over the entire page (zposition set to "front") but we'd like to specify a container within the page which it would slide over. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure it will be possible but we would need to see some existing code and if you have tried anything which we can see if there was a problem which can be fixed to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received this answer from Fred (mmenu) which worked:

```
.mm-menu {
    top: 91px !important;
    height: calc( 100% - 91px ) !important;
    width:320px !important;
}
```

This lets the menu sit off the top which is just what we wanted.